# How to print the single xml value of response soap request?

Tags: php, soap

**This is my SOAP client request code:**

```
<?php

    $cf = "DTRMRA48P55D539C";
    $chiave = "700400125745081";
    $numdoc = "AV1871102";
    $tipodoc = 1;
        //$numid = $_POST['numid'];
    $codoper = "PCCPLA66T11L719L";
    $idag = "35852";

    $wsdl = "https://portalws.inps.it/ws/wsCessioneQuintoWebTest/WsInpsCessioneQuinto.asmx?WSDL";
    $local_cert = "C:\\Apache24\htdocs\sirio2.pem";

         $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $local_cert, 'trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
    try {
        $result = $soapClient->RichiestaCedibilita(array('CodFiscale' => $cf, 'ChiavePensione' =>  $chiave, 'NumDocumento' => $numdoc, 'TipoDocumento' => 1, 'CodiceOperatore' => $codoper, 'IdentificativoAgenzia' => $idag));

    print_r($soapClient->__getlastResponse());

        $soap = print_r($soapClient->__getlastResponse());

        print_r($soap);

}

catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   echo $exception;      
}  

?>
```

**This is my response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DatiCedibilita><Cedibilita><Id>20190000277</Id><CodiceFiscale>DTRMRA48P55D539C</CodiceFiscale><ChiavePensione>700400125745081</ChiavePensione><Cognome>DTR</Cognome><Nome>MRA</Nome><DataNascita>1948-09-15</DataNascita><CodiceSede>0100</CodiceSede><DenominazioneSede>AGRIGENTO</DenominazioneSede><IndirizzoSede>VIA PICONE 20/30 - 92100 - AGRIGENTO - AG</IndirizzoSede><Importo>250.0000</Importo><DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita>2019-01-15</DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita><RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita>Istituto di Credito</RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita><DataScadenzaAOI>202002</DataScadenzaAOI><DataRilascio>2019-01-16</DataRilascio><Note></Note><ProtocolloINPS>INPS.TESTC1.16/01/2019.0000287</ProtocolloINPS><CodiceErrore>0</CodiceErrore><DescrizioneErrore></DescrizioneErrore></Cedibilita></DatiCedibilita><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DatiCedibilita><Cedibilita><Id>20190000277</Id><CodiceFiscale>DTRMRA48P55D539C</CodiceFiscale><ChiavePensione>700400125745081</ChiavePensione><Cognome>DTR</Cognome><Nome>MRA</Nome><DataNascita>1948-09-15</DataNascita><CodiceSede>0100</CodiceSede><DenominazioneSede>AGRIGENTO</DenominazioneSede><IndirizzoSede>VIA PICONE 20/30 - 92100 - AGRIGENTO - AG</IndirizzoSede><Importo>250.0000</Importo><DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita>2019-01-15</DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita><RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita>Istituto di Credito</RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita><DataScadenzaAOI>202002</DataScadenzaAOI><DataRilascio>2019-01-16</DataRilascio><Note></Note><ProtocolloINPS>INPS.TESTC1.16/01/2019.0000287</ProtocolloINPS><CodiceErrore>0</CodiceErrore><DescrizioneErrore></DescrizioneErrore></Cedibilita></DatiCedibilita>1 ?>
```

How can I print the single tag value? **For example:**

Id=20190000277

Answer (score 1):

All this lines only echos values to output

```
print_r($soapClient->__getlastResponse());
$soap = print_r($soapClient->__getlastResponse());
print_r($soap);
```

Remove lines upper and replace by below. To set $soap and get values, use xml parser, for example, simplexml library

```
$soap = $soapClient->__getlastResponse();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap);
echo $xml->Cedibilita->Id; // 20190000277
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1077870)

Comment: Hello thanks for your response....I try this: $soap = $soapClient->__getlastResponse();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap);
echo $xml->Cedibilita->Id; // 20190000277

Comment: my response is: ?>

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd call `var_dump($soap)`. This will show you the structure of the array / object which you have to work with. You can then drill down into this to output the exact value you want.

**For example (if an object):**

```
$id = $soap->id;

print("Id=" . $id);
```

**If an array:**

```
$id = $soap['id'];

print("Id=" . $id);
```

If you provide the `var_dump($soap)`, I should be able to show you exactly what code you'd need.

I hope that helps!

Comment: OP put the result of print_r($soap) in the question

Comment: this is my var_dump($soap): string(1473) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DatiCedibilita><Cedibilita><Id>20190000282</Id><CodiceFiscale>DTRMRA48P55D539C</CodiceFiscale><ChiavePensione>700400125745081</ChiavePensione><Cognome>DTR</Cognome><Nome>MRA</Nome><DataNascita>1948-09-15</DataNascita><CodiceSede>0100</CodiceSede><DenominazioneSede>AGRIGENTO</DenominazioneSede>...

Comment: @splash58 Yes but `print_r` doesn't really show the format of the array / object very well.

Comment: @serenellaangelilli Ah, it returns the entire response as a string, in which case you'll need to follow splash58 's idea of formatting that string into an XML object which you can then extract the value from.

Comment: this is my print_r($soap): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DatiCedibilita><Cedibilita><Id>20190000288</Id><CodiceFiscale>DTRMRA48P55D539C</CodiceFiscale><ChiavePensione>700400125745081</ChiavePensione><Cognome>DTR</Cognome><Nome>MRA</Nome><DataNascita>1948-09-15</DataNascita><CodiceSede>0100</CodiceSede><DenominazioneSede>AGRIGENTO</DenominazioneSede>

Comment: yes exactly!!!!  it returns the entire response as a string, in which case you'll need to follow splash58 's idea of formatting that string into an XML object which you can then extract the value from.

Comment: @serenellaangelilli Yes, but it's much easier to format it into an XML object, to then access the data.

Comment: How to format it into an XML object, to then access the data?

Comment: @serenellaangelilli By using `$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap);` as splash said.

Comment: @serenellaangelilli What happens? What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get information about functions and types for your SOAP service.

```
<?php
...
# SOAP Client
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $local_cert, 'trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));

# List functions
echo 'Functions: '.'</br>';
$functions = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
foreach($functions as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';

# List types
echo 'Types: '.'</br>';
$types = $soapClient->__getTypes();
foreach($types as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';
...

?>
```

After that, based on this information, you may try to read your SOAP response.

With your approach, `$soapClient->__getlastResponse()` returns the XML received in the last SOAP response as an XML string. In this case, you may convert this string to XML and read data:

```
<?php
$soap =     
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <DatiCedibilita>
        <Cedibilita>
            <Id>20190000277</Id>
            <CodiceFiscale>DTRMRA48P55D539C</CodiceFiscale>
            <ChiavePensione>700400125745081</ChiavePensione>
            <Cognome>DTR</Cognome>
            <Nome>MRA</Nome>
            <DataNascita>1948-09-15</DataNascita>
            <CodiceSede>0100</CodiceSede>
            <DenominazioneSede>AGRIGENTO</DenominazioneSede>
            <IndirizzoSede>VIA PICONE 20/30 - 92100 - AGRIGENTO - AG</IndirizzoSede>
            <Importo>250.0000</Importo>
            <DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita>2019-01-15</DataUltimaRichiestaCedibilita>
            <RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita>Istituto di Credito</RichiedenteUltimaCedibilita>
            <DataScadenzaAOI>202002</DataScadenzaAOI>
            <DataRilascio>2019-01-16</DataRilascio>
            <Note></Note><ProtocolloINPS>INPS.TESTC1.16/01/2019.0000287</ProtocolloINPS>
            <CodiceErrore>0</CodiceErrore>
            <DescrizioneErrore></DescrizioneErrore>
        </Cedibilita>
    </DatiCedibilita>';

# Use this in your script. I expect, that $soapClient->__getlastResponse() returns the above string.
$soap = $soapClient->__getlastResponse();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap);
echo $xml->Cedibilita->Id;
?>
```

Comment: How can I automatically convert a string to xml?

Comment: @serenellaangelilli If string is valid XML, with `simplexml_load_string()` for example. But, I think that you need to know the type of your `RichiestaCedibilita()` call and read data according to that type. In most cases, this is an array.

Comment: The response is one string...not a valid xml! i don't know how to resolve this problem

Comment: @serenellaangelilli Your responce, as is posted, contains two `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` and `1 ` at the end. Check this first. Thanks.

Comment: @serenellaangelilli xml  is a text string it's turned to Object  by calling simplexml_load_string

Comment: @splash58 Yes. I've tested it and it works if I remove the second part.

Comment: Your responce, as is posted, contains two <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> and 1 at the end. Check this first. Thanks = YES EXACTLY!

Comment: @serenellaangelilli you don't need your print_r calls, put response to the variable

Comment: @serenellaangelilli May you try to execute `var_dump($soapClient->RichiestaCedibilita(array('CodFiscale' => $cf, 'ChiavePensione' =>  $chiave, 'NumDocumento' => $numdoc, 'TipoDocumento' => 1, 'CodiceOperatore' => $codoper, 'IdentificativoAgenzia' => $idag)););`  and post the result? Thanks.

Comment: This is the response: object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["RichiestaCedibilitaResult"]=> string(839) "20190000296DTRMRA48P55D539C700400125745081DTRMRA1948-09-150100AGRIGENTOVIA PICONE 20/30 - 92100 - AGRIGENTO - AG250.00002019-01-16Istituto di Credito2020022019-01-16INPS.TESTC1.16/01/2019.00003080" }

Answer (score 0):

Hi i try this and work for me:

```
<?php

    $cf = "DTRMRA48P55D539C";
    $chiave = "700400125745081";
    $numdoc = "AV1871102";
    $tipodoc = 1;
        //$numid = $_POST['numid'];
    $codoper = "PCCPLA66T11L719L";
    $idag = "35852";

    $wsdl = "https://portalws.inps.it/ws/wsCessioneQuintoWebTest/WsInpsCessioneQuinto.asmx?WSDL";
    $local_cert = "C:\\Apache24\htdocs\sirio2.pem";

    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $local_cert, 'trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));


  $result = $soapClient->RichiestaCedibilita(array('CodFiscale' => $cf, 'ChiavePensione' =>  $chiave, 'NumDocumento' => $numdoc, 'TipoDocumento' => 1, 'CodiceOperatore' => $codoper, 'IdentificativoAgenzia' => $idag));




$xml = simplexml_load_string($result->RichiestaCedibilitaResult);
echo ($xml->Cedibilita->Id);

?>
```